# Magento 2 DI compilation issue

Tags: magento2, di

I've the run the before running setup:di:compile home page and other is working fine.After running the setup:di:compile expect home page other pages working fine.
if i'm removing the di/global.ser that i didn't face any issue but that is correct way.Please help on this i'm not sure what is the issue on that.

**Error:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given, called in E:\xampp\htdocs\Digicel-Branding\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in E:\xampp\htdocs\Digicel-Branding\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php:128 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\Digicel-Branding\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager)) #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\Digicel-Branding\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) #2 E:\xampp\htdocs\Digicel-Branding\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory in E:\xampp\htdocs\Digicel-Branding\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php on line 128
```

Answer (score 2):

Execute this command :

- rm -rf var/ generated/

Then, do process of di:compile.

Comment: you mean to say run  steps like 
step 1: Run the setup:upgrade
step 2: rm -rf var/generated
step 3: steup:di:compile
step 4: static-content:deploy

Comment: i did the same process but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Delete the var/di folder
And Upgrade the setup

Then magento will work

Comment: in production mode we need enabled the di:compile if we are removing var/di compile means what is use of compilation

Comment: before moving to production mode you need to do php -f bin/magento maintenance:enable

Comment: after moving production "php -f bin/magento maintenance:disable"

Comment: if You have more doubt check magento2 documentation

Comment: ok i'm running this command "php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production" this will run all required commands like maintance enable/Disable,upgrade ,deploy .

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the `__construct` from your extend , there seems to be an issue with this.
you should have something like

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    // other dependencies
    array $data = []
)
{
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    // other declarations
    $this->setTemplate('template_path');
}
```

This is from a block of mine so in your case it will most likely have to be different